# How to make a button pull up a webview?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

i'm making an app with moviePlayerViewController, and I am trying to add a webview when the button is pressed. It's a single page app, but the button once pressed to bring up a webview. I have already put in the code to make the webview, but I don't know how to combine it with my MoviePlayerViewController. What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To make your question more answerable, you will want to include some code. Have a read at the faq for the kind of questions you want to ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: Combine it how? You haven't said what you want to actually do. What does combine mean?  Should the movie be launched from within the UiWebView? If so is this a native button or a html button on the web page? etc.  EDIT: After just looking at your other question, I still have no idea what you are trying to do with the movie player and the web view, i.e. what is the relationship between them supposed to be. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643995/xcode-application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-en

Comment: What I meant was that I want a WebView to be pulled up when the button is pressed. Sorry for the confusion. The video is embedded in the app, as well as the button. I just needed a website to come up in a WebView when the button is pressed.